# difference between MVC and MVVM in flutter

Tags: flutter, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture

i didn't understand the difference between **mvc** and **mvvm** !

can some one explain it for me?

in mvc :

**MODEL**

```
class UserModel {
  late int id;
  late String name;
  late String email;

  UserModel({required this.id, required this.name, required this.email});

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    email = json['email'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
    };
  }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data![index].name),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                      onPressed: () {
                         UsersController.delete(snapshot.data![index].id) <----
                       },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
            future: UsersController.getAll(), <----
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class UsersController {
  Future<List<UserModel>> getAll() async {
     .....................
     return users;
  }
 Future<void> delete(id) async {
     .....................
  }
}
```

everything works as expected
now, i tried to use the  **MVVM architecture*

i used the same Model and View, and i just changed the controller to ViewModel

**ViewModel**

```
class ViewModel {
  Future<List<UserModel>> getAll() async {
     .....................
     return users;
  }
 Future<void> delete(id) async {
     .....................
  }
}
```

and nothing changed , only the class name !

I know , it's wrong !
But what i must do ?
in the mvvm , the role of the model view is to provide data to the view , and this is what i'm doing !
same controller or model view provide data the view !

can some one explain ?

Answer (score 0):

The point in the ViewModel is to taylor the response to the view that needs to be rendered.  This is hard to see when you have a straightforward CRUD application where the ViewModel and the Model are 1-1 and are directly represented in the view.

To be able to see a difference here, you would need to have either multiple models that fed into a ViewModel, or you would need to constrain your model in some way by omitting pieces.  In a larger application, you may have many ViewModels that include parts of many Models.

To extend your example, if you had a second Model called Posts, which were associated with the Users.  And you needed a view which indicated not only the user information, but how many posts they had, then you would create a ViewModel which added the NumberOfPosts to the ViewModel before returning it to the View layer.  Your models would never contain that value, it would just be derived from the combination of your models.